# how to load database url and credentials from a properties file in BIRT

Tags: birt

BIRT 4.2.1 run-time package deployed into Tomcat server. Now, I would like to read database url and credentials from a properties file and bind with data source properties.
Is it possible to configure the properties in web.xml (BIRT_HOME/WEB_INF/web.xml) and use it?

I have read this post [Birt data source parameters from a property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340339/birt-data-source-parameters-from-a-property-file)

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but can't you just pass the connection to the DB instead?